# Why do I get an 'undefined' error when calling Blazor JSInterop function?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

I am currently working on a Blazor Server app where I am in need of print functionality. I would like to print a certain element/div on the page using Javascript interop. The problem is that when I try code that usually should work in plain JS, I get an error that the function is not defined.

This is the code I keep in my _Host.cshtml

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        async function printDiv() {
            var divContents = document.getElementById("toprint").innerHTML;
            var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
            a.document.open();
            a.document.write('<html>');
            a.document.write('<body > <br>');
            a.document.write(divContents);
            a.document.write('</body></html>');
            a.document.close();
            a.print();
        }
    </script>
```

This is the C# function that calls the JS code:

`public async Task PrintTest() => await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("printDiv");`

The element looks like this:

```
    <div id="toprint">
         <div id="printdiv" class="print">
                <BarcodeGenerator @ref="barcodegen" Code="@place" ElementId="barcode" FullWidth>         </BarcodeGenerator>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the exception that I get:

[JSInterop Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg9Z8.png)

Comment: Yeah, don't render things using JS in Blazor. Blazor Server keeps internal representation of DOM in a circuit on the server. Modifying DOM via JS can lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay, do you have an idea of how I could do this without modifying DOM from JS? Also the interesting thing is that when I leave only the `a.document.write(divContents)` and delete all other writes, it works...

Comment: Yes, use html markup string. That may wors for now. You never know.

Comment: Try without the `async` in the function definition. @maciek - this code is not modifying the DOM - it is creating a new window/document.

Comment: @MisterMagoo I have tried it, still getting the same exception

Comment: Where/when/how is the printTest declared/invoked?

Comment: @MisterMagoo it is invoked with an OnClick on a button. On the same .razor page where the BarcodeGenerator element is located. I have decided to use the Blazor.Printing service available on GitHub as I was not able to make this work. Thank you for the help.